# Error al pasar variables con Intent - NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

Estoy intentando pasar un `ArrayList<Pet>` desde un `Fragment` a mi `MainActivity.java` para desde aquí, si se pulsa un `ImageButton` (de la barra de acción) vayamos a otra actividad en la cual necesito los datos de dicho ArrayList.
Pues bien, creo un `Intent`en mi clase `Fragment` y un `bundle`para recibir estos datos en mi `MainActivity` y me salta una excepción `NullPointerException` al recibir estos datos.

Código del `Intent` de la clase `Fragment`

```
//Intent
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), MainActivity.class);
String [] nombre = new String [pets.size()];
int []numeroLikes = new int[pets.size()];
int []foto = new int [pets.size()];
for (int i = 0;i<pets.size();i++){
    nombre [i] = pets.get(i).getPetName();
    numeroLikes[i]=pets.get(i).getNumberOfLikes();
    foto[i] = pets.get(i).getFoto();
}
intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.nombre_mascota),nombre);
intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.numberOfLikes),numeroLikes);
intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.foto),foto);
startActivity(intent);
```

Código del `Bundle` para recibir los datos en `MainActivity`

```
//Bundle para inicializar pets
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String [] nombres = bundle.getStringArray(getString(R.string.nombre_mascota));
int [] nLikes = bundle.getIntArray(getString(R.string.numberOfLikes));
int [] foto  = bundle.getIntArray(getString(R.string.foto));
for (int i = 0; i<nombres.length;i++){
    pets.add(new Pet(nLikes[i],nombres[i],foto[i]));
}
```

En este punto me salta el error, en la línea:

```
String [] nombres = bundle.getStringArray(getString(R.string.nombre_mascota));
```

No se por qué razón me sale un `nullPointerException` si todas las referencias están bien puestas. Si es un error de lógica de programación me gustaría que me lo comentaseis también.

No se si será importante pero comento que mi `Fragment` está compuesto por un `RecyclerView`

El error es el siguiente:

```
08-26 09:19:07.807 8061-8061/es.uclm.mylittlepets E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: es.uclm.mylittlepets, PID: 8061
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{es.uclm.mylittlepets/es.uclm.mylittlepets.Layout.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String[] android.os.Bundle.getStringArray(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String[] android.os.Bundle.getStringArray(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at es.uclm.mylittlepets.Layout.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:55)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

EDIT 1:
`pets`, el ArrayList, sí que tiene datos. Justo antes del Intent, llamo al método `inicializarMascotas()` cuyo contenido es:

```
public void inicializarMascotas(){
    pets.add(new Pet(0,"Pet1",R.drawable.perro));
    pets.add(new Pet(0,"Pet2",R.drawable.burro));
    pets.add(new Pet(0,"Pet3", R.drawable.cangrejo));
    pets.add(new Pet(0,"Pet4",R.drawable.gallo));
    pets.add(new Pet(0,"Pet5",R.drawable.pulpo));
}
```

El constructor de la clase `Pet` recibe: `(int numeroLikes, String nombre_mascota, int foto)`

EDIT 2:

Un usuario me comentó que debería probar implementando la interfaz `Parcelable`, y así lo he hecho.

1.- En mi POJO `Pet`, he implementado `Parcelable` con sus métodos obligatorios.

```
@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeInt(numberOfLikes);
    parcel.writeInt(foto);
    parcel.writeString(petName);
}
public void readToParcel (Parcel parcel){
    numberOfLikes = parcel.readInt();
    foto = parcel.readInt();
    petName = parcel.readString();
}
```

He añadido también un constructor de la siguiente forma:

```
public Pet (Parcel parcel){
    readToParcel(parcel);
}
```

Por último, también se ha sobreescrito esto:

```
 public static final Parcelable.Creator<Pet> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Pet>() {
    @Override
    public Pet createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Pet(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Pet[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Pet[size];
    }
};
```

2.- En mi clase `Fragment` de origen, el `Intent` queda de la siguiente forma:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("array",pets);
    startActivity(intent);
```

3.- En mi clase `MainActivity` he recibido los datos así:

```
pets = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("array");
```

Si intento hacer algo del tipo:

```
Log.i("nombre", pets.get(0).getPetName());
```

El error que me da es exactamente el mismo de arriba en esta última línea.

EDIT 3:
Con la respuesta del usuario [@dddenis](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/2676/dddenis), no sale la excepción `NullPointerException` pero parece entrar en un bucle infinito en el que se repiten estas líneas en el `logcat`:

> 08-29 10:13:50.414 14960-15004/es.uclm.mylittlepets E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x9ece3960
>
> 08-29 10:13:50.439 14960-14960/es.uclm.mylittlepets I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
>
> 08-29 10:13:50.509 14960-15004/es.uclm.mylittlepets W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
>
> 08-29 10:13:50.509 14960-15004/es.uclm.mylittlepets W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x9e66c200, error=EGL_SUCCESS
>
> 08-29 10:13:50.532 14960-14960/es.uclm.mylittlepets E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
>
> 08-29 10:13:50.584 14960-14960/es.uclm.mylittlepets E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
>
> 08-29 10:13:50.612 14960-14960/es.uclm.mylittlepets I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.

Comment: ¿Has intenta do implementar la interfaz Parcelable (Serialización de Android) y pasarlo en el Bundle tal cual con su clave de extra?

Comment: No, no lo he probado pero lo haré y comentaré que ocurre.

Comment: He editado mi pregunta con la implementación de la interfaz `Parcelable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He conseguido finalmente pasar los datos del `Fragment` a `MainActivity`. Lo he hecho de la siguiente forma:

> EN MI CLASE `Fragment`.

1.-Creo una interfaz `FragmentIterationListener` que voy a usar para comunicarme con la `Activity`.

```
public interface FragmentIterationListener{
    public void onFragmentIteration(Bundle parameters);
}
```

Creamos un atributo `private FragmentIterationListener mcallback`  que usaremos para pasar datos a la `Activity`.

2.- En el método `onAttach(Activity activity)` hacemos lo siguiente:

```
try {
        mcallback = (FragmentIterationListener) activity;
    }catch(ClassCastException ex){
        Log.e("PetsFragment","El activity debe implementar la interfaz FragmentIterationListener");
    }
```

De esta forma asignamos a nuestro atributo el `Activity`con el cual se va a comunicar.

3.- En el método `onCreateView()`, además de inflar el `Layout` instanciamos nuestro `RecyclerView`.

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rvPets);
```

4.- En el método `onViewCreated()` establecemos el `RecyclerView` como un `LinearLayout`, inicializamos el `ArrayList <Pet> pets` y se lo pasamos a la clase `MainActivity` de la siguiente forma:

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putParcelableArrayList("EXTRA_PETS", pets);
mcallback.onFragmentIteration(extras);
```

> EN MI CLASE `MainActivity.java`

1.- Implementamos la interfaz que hemos creado anteriormente:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements PetsFragment.FragmentIterationListener{
```

2.- Implementamos el método obligatorio de esta interfaz:

```
public void onFragmentIteration(Bundle parameters) {
    pets = parameters.getParcelableArrayList("EXTRA_PETS");
}
```

3.- Recibimos los datos de la siguiente forma (en el método `onCreate()`):

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
onFragmentIteration(bundle);
```

Answer (score 1):

El error dice que `getString(R.string.nombre_mascota) == null` por lo tanto, cuando aqui `intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.nombre_mascota),nombre);` le pasas `nombre == null`.

Comment: ¿De qué forma podría corregir esto entonces?

Comment: `pets` tiene datos? yo lo que haria es debugar para ver que hay antes de añadir al intent....

Comment: He actualizado y creo que te respondo a tú pregunta, `pets` sí que tiene datos.

Answer (score 1):

En tu código tanto el envio

```
intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.nombre_mascota),nombre);
```

como la recepción del arreglo es correcta:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String [] nombres = bundle.getStringArray(getString(R.string.nombre_mascota));
```

Me llama la atención este detalle:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'java.lang.String[]
>   android.os.Bundle.getStringArray(java.lang.String)' on a null object
>   reference

Estas ejecutando el método `getStringArray()` de una instancia bundle que tiene el valor null.

Usa `getActivity()` en lugar de `getContext()` para obtener el contexto de la Activity en el fragmento y usarlo en tu intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
```

Comment: He ejecutado el "Clean Project" y "Rebuild Project" y aun así sigue dando el mismo error.

Comment: He editado mi pregunta el bundle es null , usa getActivity() para configurar tu intent que abrira la Activity, no getContext().

Comment: Hola Elena, gracias por tu respuesta pero aun usando `getActivity()` en el `Intent`, sigue dando exactamente el mismo error.

Answer (score 1):

1. Implementa la interfaz **`Parcelable`** en **`Pet`**.
2. Prepara el **`Bundle`** con un **`ArrayList<Pet>`** con el método **`putParcelableArrayList(key,value)`**.
3. Recibe el **`ArrayList<Pet>`** con el método **`getParcelableArrayList(key)`** del **`Bundle`**.

> DATOS A ENVIAR

```
List<Pet> pets = new ArrayList<Pet>(){
    {
        add(new Pet(0,"Pet1",R.drawable.perro));
        add(new Pet(0,"Pet2",R.drawable.burro));
        add(new Pet(0,"Pet3", R.drawable.cangrejo));
        add(new Pet(0,"Pet4",R.drawable.gallo));
        add(new Pet(0,"Pet5",R.drawable.pulpo));
    }
};
```

> PREPARACIÓN DE LOS DATOS

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putParcelableArrayList("EXTRA_PETS", (ArrayList<Pet>) pets);
```

> ENVÍO DE DATOS

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class).putExtras(extras);
startActivity(intent);
```

> RECEPCIÓN DE DATOS

```
List<Pet> petsReceived = getIntent().getParcelableArrayList("EXTRA_PETS");
```

*PD: Se puede realizar también (y en muchos menos pasos), con la Serialización que ofrece Java, pero no se aconseja por rendimiento.*

Comment: En mi última edición, he comentado un problema al ejecutar justo lo que dices. Al hacer debugging, observo que la variable `petsReceived` sigue siendo nula

Comment: Umm, cierto. ¿Has intentado con un callback de la Activity implementado por tu Fragment (y recibido en el onAttach)? Aquí un post: https://laaptu.wordpress.com/tag/android-passind-data-from-fragment-to-activity/

Comment: Estoy viendo el post y no sabría como implementar eso en mi código. Ahí lo hace con un `TextView`, ¿en mi caso tendría que pasar un `RecyclerView`?